# Cloud Function behind a load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I followed the guide of GCP and deployed the hello-world PHP sample as a function with connections allowed only from internal and from Cloud Load Balancing.
After that I configured the load balancer in order to use the function as backend.
Everything is in the same project.
I would have expected the function to be invoked, instead I kept getting a 403 error:

Error: Forbidden

Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server.

After struggling for a while i granted allUsers the Cloud Functions Invoker role and everything worked as expected but it seems to me that there is an error.

Why do I need to allow allUsers if both the load balancer and the function are in the same project?
And why trying to allow allAuthenticatedUsers it stops to work?

I'm new to GCP so please apologize me if I'm missing something.

Comment: if `allUsers` is not specified, then only authorized identities can access the Cloud Function. The means that the client must include the HTTP `authorization: bearer identity_token` header when making requests.

Answer (score 0):

As John mentioned, if allusers is not specified, only the authorize users can access to CF. You can take a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#authenticating_function_to_function_calls) documentation to know more about how to authenticate to a CF. But basically it is needed the roles/cloudfunctions.invoker role to the SA you want to use to access to.

On the other hand, it is possible to Generate tokens programmatically by using the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#generating_tokens_programmatically).

```
def make_authorized_get_request(service_url):
    """
    make_authorized_get_request makes a GET request to the specified HTTP endpoint
    in service_url (must be a complete URL) by authenticating with the
    ID token obtained from the google-auth client library.
    """

    req = urllib.request.Request(service_url)

    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, service_url)

    req.add_header("Authorization", f"Bearer {id_token}")
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    return response.read()
```